# In typescript, why is a union of enums not also an enum?

Tags: typescript, string, enums, union

I have two enums that I would like to union.

```
enum Color {
    RED = 'red',
    BLUE = 'blue',
}

enum Shape {
    CIRCLE = 'circle',
    SQUARE = 'square',
}
```

However when I declare a union type and attempt to reference a member:

```
type ColorShape = Color | Shape;
const test: ColorShape = ColorShape.RED;
```

I get a compile time error:

> TS2693: 'ColorShape' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

Why is this? Would an union of enums not also be an enum itself?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between *types* (that exist in TypeScript and are erased when compiled to JavaScript) and *values* (that exist at runtime in JavaScript)?  An enum like `enum Foo { a = "x" }` brings into scope both a *value* (essentially `const Foo = {a: "x"}`) and a *type* (essentially `type Foo = "x"`).  When you define a new type `type Baz = Foo | Bar` you are not defining a new value.  If you want a new value you will need to make it yourself (e.g., `const FooBar = Object.assign({}, Foo, Bar));`).  Sort of like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ4OVN).

Comment: Does that answer your question? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Also, the bit at the beginning about the `parseStringEnumFromValue()` seems to be a little off-topic in that there are some other issues being brought up (why would you use conditional types at all there instead of just [using a generic constraint](https://tsplay.dev/wjkV8N) or [simplify the implementation](https://tsplay.dev/we4VaW) etc etc etc.)  You might want to just get rid of that and [edit] to provide a [mre] like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WG5pXN) that only focuses on why a union of enum types does not bring an enum value into scope.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that specific difference between what types and enums are compiled to (and I had been trying to search for their differences as well). That definitely helps me get closer to understanding, so thank you. Let me play around with it for a bit to see if I fully understand.

Comment: You're right. I'm including too much info. I'll pare it down.

Comment: I edited the question. There is still something I fundamentally don't understand. Why are the resulting type aliases different in this [example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwLACgq6gJQFEARKAXigHJlgATSgGmzygCEAZAVUPKoCMEYYI2wBfbNlCQoAZQAWAQwAOwdMzwwAkvhjseFSgGMAlskMJhTHHhkBFTgEEivSgGcAjmAU0RWcVmxDOBBXABcoVAp4JGQAOiJiAG5A4LCoQ155ZWBYrR09ZICsUIBPFVhEFCyVThBjYN5olCgAH1lFFUSoAHpuqAUEYwVXKAAzZqbUNurgFJDwyZneAHk+ACtgQ1DY4ddjAHMQAAo0UQYKmPOZgEpC0vLFjuAAFTLVCnvgOFGLqqeu3r9QbDMbNT7fX6oABkUHBPxm2CAA)?

Comment: I don't understand the question, sorry.  Why are which type aliases different from what?  Is it a question about the names you gave them?  Or something else?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I added a comment [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJygbwLACgq6gJQFEARKAXigHJlgATSgGmzygCEAZAVUPKoCMEYYI2wBfbNlCQoAZQAWAQwAOwdMzwwAkvhjseFSgGMAlskMJhTHHhkBFTgEEivSgGcAjmAU0RWcVmxDOBBXABcoVAp4JGQAOiJiAG5A4LCoQ155ZWBYrR09ZICsUIBPFVhEFCyVThBjYN5olCgAH1lFFUSoAHpuqAUEYwVXKAAzZqbUNurgFJDwyZneAHk+ACtgQ1DY4ddjAHMQAAo0UQYKmPOZgEpC0vLFjuAAFTLVCnvgOFGLqqeu3r9QbDMbNT7fX6oABkUHBPxm6hYSORKNRKMBmko0CCIFGYFcdCgAHc5CUoMYRqE5BSoAA9ckjBwAOVIxnmwAUtCgEOW+CggwA1qo2bC5KpHtlavUQNggA) about the specific difference that I don't understand.

Comment: Ah, well if you have two objects like `{a: 0}` and `{b: 1}` and you shove them together into a single object like `{a: 0, b: 1}`, then that single object's type is the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the individual types, since it has the `a` key *and* the `b` key.  But if you then take that object and read a random property value from it, the type will be either `0` *or* `1`, that is the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `0 | 1`.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Such an explanation is probably out of scope for the question as asked, though, so I wouldn't go into that in the answer.  The answer is mostly just "an `enum` declaration brings both a value and a type into scope, and if you want to combine them you have to create both a value and a type manually.  Doing one doesn't do the other".  If that's okay I'll write it up; let me know.

Comment: Yes that write up would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is important to keep in mind the difference in TypeScript between TypeScript *types*, which exist at compile time and are [erased](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#erased-types) from the emitted JavaScript code; and JavaScript *values*, which also exist at runtime and appear in the emitted JavaScript code.  TypeScript tries to keep track of values and types, but JavaScript only knows about values.

Most of the time when you make a declaration in TypeScript you are either bringing a value into scope or a type into scope but not both:

```
// values
const foo = 123;
function bar() { }

// types
type Baz = { a: number };
interface Qux { b: string }
```

In the above, `foo` and `bar` are values that exist in the emitted JavaScript, while `Baz` and `Qux` are types that are erased.

And note that values and types have completely different namespaces; you can have a value and a type with the same name, and they don't have to be related to each other.  The compiler doesn't confuse them:

```
// separate namespaces
const Xyz = { z: 1 };
type Xyz = { y: string };
```

Here `Xyz` is the name of a value (an object with a `z` property whose value is `1`) and also the name of a type (an object type with a `y` property whose value type is `string`).  These are unrelated.  If I write `const uvw = Xyz;` then I'm writing value-level code that makes it to JavaScript and therefore the `Xyz` is the value.  If I write `interface Rst extends Xyz { }` then I'm writing type-level code that's erased from JavaScript and therefore the `Xyz` is the type.

---

Okay, so most of the time when you declare some named thing, that thing is either a type or a value but not both.  But there are two declarations that do bring into existence both a value and a type of the same name: [the `class` declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) and [the `enum` declaration](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html):

```
// both
class Abc { c = "" }
enum Def { D = "e" }
```

Here the name `Abc` refers to both a class constructor *value* that you can reference at runtime like `new Abc()`, and it also refers to a class instance *type* that you can use at compile time to talk about class instances like `const instance: Abc = ...`.  And if you write `const instance: Abc = new Abc()` you are referring first to the type and then to the value.

Similarly, the name `Def` refers to both an enum object *value* that you can reference at runtime like `Def.D === "e"`, and it also refers to an enum *type* that is the union of the types of the enum member values like `const def: Def = ...`.  And if you write `const def: Def = Def.D` you are referring first to the type and then to the value.

---

Now, while `class` is part of JavaScript (since ES2015), `enum` is not.  So when you write an `enum` the compiler will essentially [downlevel](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html#downleveling) it to some JavaScript.  Let's look at your `Color` enum:

```
enum Color {
    RED = 'red',
    BLUE = 'blue',
}
```

This more or less compiles to something that acts like

```
const Color = {
  RED: "red",
  BLUE: "blue"
}
```

It's just a plain object.  Meanwhile the type `Color` is something that acts like

```
type Color = "red" | "blue";
```

That's not strictly true because `enum`s are "marked" so that you can't just assign a string to them, but it's close enough for our purposes.  So when your `enum Color` declaration is similar to the combination of the above value and type declarations.

---

Now, when you write

```
type ColorShape = Color | Shape;
```

You are creating a `ColorShape` *type*.  But `type ColorShape = ...` is not an `enum`, and so all you've done is create the type.  There is no corresponding value brought into existence here.  You've only done half the work in creating a combined `enum`-like thing.  If you want the corresponding value, you will have to create it manually.

What you want is something that looks like `{RED: "red", BLUE: "blue", CIRCLE: "circle", SQUARE: "square"}`.  There are multiple ways to take the `Color` value and the `Shape` value and make such an object.

You could use [the `Object.assign()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```
const ColorShape = Object.assign({}, Color, Shape);
// const ColorShape: typeof Color & typeof Shape
```

Or you could use [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals):

```
const ColorShape = { ...Color, ...Shape };
/* const ColorShape: {
    CIRCLE: Shape.CIRCLE;
    SQUARE: Shape.SQUARE;
    RED: Color.RED;
    BLUE: Color.BLUE;
} */
```

Either way should work.  Once you've done this, *now*, you can (mostly) use `ColorShape` as if it were a combined `enum` composed of `Color` and `Shape`:

```
const test: ColorShape = ColorShape.RED; // okay
```

---

Note that I said "mostly".  The `enum` declaration also brings a few more types into scope; it actually acts as a [`namespace`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) where you can use the dotted path to enum values as types themselves:

```
interface RedState {
    name: string;
    color: Color.RED // <-- this is a type
}
```

But that doesn't happen with either of your `ColorShape` definitions:

```
interface RedState {
    name: string;
    color: ColorShape.RED // error!
    // 'ColorShape' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.
}
```

You probably don't care about that.  If somehow you do, then the only way I know how to do this is to manually create your `ColorShape` namespace and export each type from it:

```
namespace ColorShape {
    export type CIRCLE = typeof ColorShape.CIRCLE;
    export type SQUARE = typeof ColorShape.SQUARE;
    export type RED = typeof ColorShape.RED;
    export type BLUE = typeof ColorShape.BLUE;
}
```

Not great, and probably not anything you need.  But for completeness I figured I'd just show that there's a bit more going on under the hood with `enum`s.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEDcEMBsFcFMDOBYAUAYwPYDtEBdQAzTTUAXlAEYAmAZgG41DZt08BLHUAI0gCcAFAEpQAb1ABfNGhCg8ATwAOSNAuWgAQpABe5MaEgAuUNlgBbbvD6TGqdtjxXCkdPFABFWAA993Y-j57AHNJaVRZRHhFfkhHE0gzJGjXFAwcfFAADXldCnFtY0obVSU3bNz9eX88QOwQiVsw2W5MPAALNHRoSEREUABBbnR9YYoAIjHQ1HhTM1AAEXhCfXm9MfhJqVQwmfNQAGFMaExrUTRQC9AAJQBRVYoAcj54ABMHgBpzy40AGQBVG56B7cODwD5oLZoXZzADKbUg6jOqEuBwAkld9j9AY90Ow+F0wZ9kZcYe4-v1bkDEABHWD8QkQsJqNyHY58OEItwUVknUAAH1AHOUjXCACpOukCDz2fD1BQAPLcABW8DYADoeoh2EFsAJRBJ3gcjidDUL4EJbLIsLgpcaZZzjMzMMtpaAAGRyUrOwWy+BoUXAMLWjLSs16cRqyPSw2RtVhhoyUWgYO2tlm4xIlH7dGYm7GM1q7MYrG2FGk8m3fO+uNkik3UuXW7zYzStVNhsXX4Alt2tVd+sQ0ABoOSuRIPA9tO+vSh6vt0CyTAAa0g8jC9kcfGcrmurxheFibkzl2wCXg1VqQQ7ybtk5ObbuC7AAB4ALSvuRtdh9b8GT3KRltiA09EkQZIWTtMNjwueAvEUE4CGZNFi2xf94G9WdOULHMSy+GC4IQtDBVrSkKCdF1IOrcs62vWD4L4RDSmuR8yK9Cipyw9s8NAOjCKQ-s9HIo0OOUPt-gHVBISAjcnBcNwrj3A9HGoMRuJA89QACYJrywNk73tUSm0AsIgA)

Comment: Extremely clear and thoughtful explanation. I find it especially interesting that values and types can have the same name without conflict. I sincerely appreciate your help!